# Does anyone know how reCAPTCHA v2 can be solved by doing web scraping with selenium in python?

Tags: web, recaptcha, screen-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping with selenium in python, the rest of the code is fine, I only need the most difficult to solve the reCAPTCHA v2

Answer (score 0):

Look into services like DeathByCaptcha that offer an API for you to submit captcha info, and return a solution.